# How to copy IIS configuration to another machine

Tags: visual-studio, iis

How can you copy an IIS configuration to another machine so that settings are not lost and do not have to be set up from scratch on the new machine?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/publish/using-web-deploy/synchronize-iis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your description, I suggest you could try to use shared configuration to achieve your requirement.

You could refer to below steps:

1.Open IIS management console and select your server

2.Find the Shared Configuration

[image]

3.Click “Export Configuration” and type in the password

4.Copy the files to the new server

[image]

5.On the new server, go back to the “Shared Configuration” section and check “Enable shared configuration.” Enter the location in physical path to these files and apply them.
It should prompt for the encryption password(if you set it) and reset IIS.